# Serializable field value of Non-Roman Letter not working in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, unicode, char, serializable

```
[SerializeField] char _letter = 'a';
```

is working fine, assignable from the inspector

```
[SerializeField] char _letter = 'অ';
```

Unity just hangs. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the character code to declare the char instead.

```
private char bengaliA = '\u0985';
```

Tested and able to render to screen.

Comment: Actually, with simple Debug.log it is working fine, printing into the console, but whenever trying to using the same when some conditions are running in the bengaliA/Letter variable, unity just hangs. Using 'a' everything works fine. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: tried even with Cyrillic(Russian) alphabet, Japanese alphabet, all working fine, but hangs with any Indian language

Comment: Please update your question with the actual use.